# How to add parameters to a Sqllitecommand

Tags: .net, sqlite

i'm using vs2008 and SQLLite.Net,
when i using these code:

```
String sel = "select * from admins where [name]='admin88' and [password]='123456'";
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = Config.connStr;
conn.Open();

System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand cmd = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand();


cmd.CommandText = sel;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.Connection = conn;

DataSet set = new DataSet();
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter adp = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter() ;
adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
adp.Fill(set);
adp.Dispose();

Response.Write(set.Tables.count);
```

it works.
but when i using parameters ,return null:

```
String sel = "select * from admins where [name]=@name and [password]=@pass";
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameter("@name", "admin88"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameter("@pass", "123456"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref: [SQL As Understood By SQLite](http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

> :AAAA     A colon followed by an identifier name holds a spot for a named
>   parameter with the name :AAAA. Named parameters are also numbered.

Your query should be as:

```
String sel = "select * from admins where [name]= :name and [password]= :pass";
```

Add parameters without @ symbol. Check the following code snippet.

```
SQLiteParameter[] myParams = new SQLiteParameter[]  
    { 
      new SQLiteParameter("DeptNo", 10), 
      new SQLiteParameter("DName", "COUNTING") 
    }; 
  SQLiteConnection sqConnection1 = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource=mydatabase.db"); 
  CreateCommand(sqConnection1,"UPDATE Dept SET DName = :DName WHERE DeptNo = :DeptNo",myParams);
```

Reference [this](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand~Parameters.html).